# I've my function written correctly at least I think it is but it appears it doesn't work

Tags: php, function, panel, admin

I'm working on an simple admin panel but when I login, my function appears to be only working the else, I'm not a pro programmer but I think that here is no error :s

```
<?php
session_start();

function loggedin(){
if(isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && !empty($_SESSION['user_id'])){
    return true;
}   else {
    return false;
}
}
if(loggedin()){
        $my_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
        $user_query = mysql_query("SELECT username, user_level FROM users    WHERE id='$my_id'");
        $run_user = mysql_fetch_array($user_query);
        $username = $run_user['username'];
        $user_level = $run_user['user_level'];
        $query_level = mysql_query("SELECT name from user_level WHERE id='$user_level'");
        $run_level= mysql_fetch_array($query_level);
        $level_name = $run_level['name'];
}

 ?>
```

Comment: what do you want to get in the end?

Comment: do you like to write `login/register` system?

Comment: Don't you need to make your session global inside the function so the function can access the session value ? since you're opening your session outside of the function. so something like `global $_SESSION['user_id'];` just after your function loggedin() {

Answer (score 0, accepted):

output every variable. make code as comment. check if your code works without loggedin() and so on. Check every code line and find the error. Learn to find errors :D good work ))

AND CHECK THE php.ini FILE ERROR_REPORTING if no error is shown.

Comment: I'm kinda newbie to programming, I know only the basics, and I'm very lazy, that's why I dont write comments xD the Error reporting thing I already checked on my php.ini and it's correct.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you are actually giving `$_SESSION['user_id']` a value?

Until you give it a value e.g. `1` the function will always return false as it would be NULL.

Comment: I've written this code, by watching in a tutorial and listening and copying the code on the video, I'm a newbie to programming so I don't know a lot of things. Already checked his code a hundred times and I can't get it to work :s this is the playlist I've watched http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-FRRCMf_WL0&list=PLGCjwl1RrtcSk5kQrBKMfDaU7KQD1phY9

Comment: Try doing `var_dump($_SESSION);` and paste the contents into your original question.